# How to speed up copying/creating a file many times in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

So, I'm setting up student surveys in a college. There are lots of forms to be handed out to lots of groups of students. For one particular survey, I have a template google form.

What I do is a loop that on every iteration creates a copy of this template and then modifies it a little bit. It takes A LOT of time. Google is copying and modifying 220 forms for like 40-50 minutes. I found my way around the time limit put on google script, but it's still too long. Do you see any way to speed this up a little?

Now it looks schematically like this:

```js
for(some range):{
   template.makeCopy("template", formsFolder);      
   var formFile = formsFolder.getFilesByName("template").next();
   var form = FormApp.openById(formFile.getId())
//   ... do some modifications
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`File#makeCopy`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination) already hands you the exact file you want, so you can completely cut out the need to search for the file you create:

```
for (var f = 0; f < newNames.length; ++f) {
  var formFile = template.makeCopy(newNames[f], formsFolder);
  var form = FormApp.openById(formFile.getId());
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that your script actually finishes and does not timeout as the maximum script run time is [30 minutes or so dependent on your edition](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#flexible_quotas_early_access). I have had a very similar obstacle where I needed to run a script over 200-300 different sheets and copy data. The number of calls to the API was about 3-5 per loop and then some javascript to filter that dataset before writing to a sheet.  It would regularly fail.

I found that my best approach was to leverage Triggers and rather than have 300 sheets processed at once have 100 sheets processed every 5 minutes or so. In my circumstances there really was no reason why these sheets had to be processed at the exact same time as long as my parameters for filtering was accurate.  I would control all the parameters through inputs on a sheet.

Comment: In my case, I've made a separate js function that runs my main script with 20 loops per run and finishes when it's done creating all the forms. This way it does not time out (every time script runs under 5 minutes), but still takes very long.

Comment: I do not think there is much else you can do if you've followed the Best Practices for Google App Scripts. At some level you are fighting against the number of API calls you are making during a session.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices